# invokeAll takes longer to return than the sum of constituent futures

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the ExecutorService.invokeAll version that takes a collection of callables and a timeout. I am timing the running time of each individual callable, and the sum of these individual running times is less than the timeout specified. I am making sure that my fixed size thread pool has atleast twice as many threads as the number of callables. Also I have made sure that the underlying threadpool queue is usually empty, which means I don't have a fast producer slow consumer problem. Still I am seeing the invokeAll timing out a lot. Any insight is appreciated?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Re, "I am making sure that my fixed size thread pool has atleast twice as many threads as the number of callables."  What is the point of creating twice as many threads as your code will be able to use?

Comment: Re, "I have made sure that the underlying threadpool queue is usually empty."  Are you saying that the same thread pool is being used for other purposes at the same time as when you do your experiment?

Comment: Reason for having twice as many threads is just to ensure that tasks aren't getting queued up. No the threadpool queue is only used for this one thing, however based on the fact that it's mostly empty I am judging that the tasks don't spend a considerable amount of time sitting on the queue.